# How should I split this part into two?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, 3d-printing

[image]

I’ve attached an image of a part I manufacture using 3d printing. I start with gold filament before switching to black mid-way. I’m hoping to simplify production by printing this as two pieces instead of one, split by color. What I’m wondering is, how should the parts be joined after splitting while minimizing the gap between them.

My thoughts so far: Screws, Snap-fit, Twist Fit. Screws would be easy to add but they would increase the part count and assembly time. Snap-fits - easy assembly but not sure how secure they would be or if they would break due to the part orientation. Twist fit might work best, but I wanted to ask here to see if there were any bother options or drawbacks I hadn’t considered.

Comment: You've forgotten to tell us what it is supposed to do and to give us a drawing that shows the cross-section and dimensions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can’t get the exact dimentiomd and cross section right now but it’s about 3.5 inches in diameter and maybe 2.5 in height. It’s the base for this mechanical dice box: https://www.instagram.com/p/CQ_JBY1BJF1/?utm_medium=copy_link

Comment: That's very nice! It looks like a stepped flange and cyanoacrylate might do the job.

Comment: Snaps concealed in the interior of the part would be a nice way to go. But might take more TLC to design well compared, to an interference fit or glue job. Axisymmetric situation is helpful, as you could use a fit of two cones with slightly different angles making the interference, possibly with the inner one split to enhance flexibility, and then just need the lip on the inner part, to catch. https://www.plasticstoday.com/injection-molding/injection-molding-design-fundamentals-snap-fits-plastic-parts

Comment: @Transistor Thank you! Hadn't thought of a stepped flange. Will give that a shot!

Answer (score 1):

If you're the designer of this dice box, it's an admirable creation. Please share the program with which you created the box.

It's likely that you also have the ability to create inside/outside threads for the full diameter. It isn't "screws" as noted in your question and not quite twist fit, but you can be assured that it will work with suitable tuning. If you require no separation, a drop of glue on the threads will prevent that.

Comment: I am, thank you! I used Fusion 360 to create it. There's definitely room to create inner threads in the top part. I'll try to test that out in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a press-fit might do the job just fine. I'm not sure to what accuracy the dimensions can be controlled in a 3D printer, but if possible, an interference of 10-20 microns would be fine for a dice-box as it is just going to be the base for the dice. You can use a softer material to give the impact on the golden base circumferentially and create the press-fit. And yaa, you will have to change the design to a stepped golden base, $OD_1$ being the $ID$ of the black gear, $OD_2$ being the $OD$ of the black gear.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I’ll try to attach an image tomorrow, but I ended up extruding a .2mm circle from the gold base with the ID of the gear. That way, I could align the two pieces. Then, I used superglue to attach them.

Comment: Oh. That would do, but it might look a bit low in the aesthetics point of view, maybe. You will have to carefully apply the glue so as to not leak it out through the seam when pressing. A mechanical fit is always preferable.